# Event invokation from multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net

I have the follwing code:

```
public class Messenger
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    public void OnPrivateMessage(string message)
    {
        if (MessageReceived != null)
        {
            MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        }
    }

    public void OnPublicMessage(string message)
    {
        if (MessageReceived != null)
        {
            MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        }
    }
}
```

OnPrivateMessage and OnPublicMessage are called from different threads. Is it thread safe to call the same event from different threads?

Comment: What do you mean with "thread safe" in this context? "Can two invocations of the event handler code occur concurrently?" - yes, they can.

Comment: @Fildor I mean is there any chance that the parameter will be corrupted between the threads. Lets say that thread 1 calls OnPrivateMesage and pass "Private Message" and a little bit later thread 2 calls OnPublicMessage  just before thread 1 invokes MessageReceived and pass "Public Message". Is there any chance that both event subscribers will get "Public Message".

Comment: No they share the same instance

Comment: All event registrees' event handlers will be invoked with both messages. The problem lies inside the event handling code. One execution of it may be interrupted by the second. So events can "overtake" in one registree if not synchronized.

Comment: I have only one susbcriber and multiple event thread invokators. THis subscriber will get both messages or it will get corrupted messages

Comment: The message itself is not "corrupted". But the event handler code may execute concurrently. So if for example the subscriber sets a field to the value of the message, one of them could go missing. It definitely can mess up object state.

Comment: ok. But if that was the scenario the same problem can occur while the two threads calling the event and passing the parameter one might mess up object state.

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: OK Thanks. What is the solution to that problem?

Comment: If you know that problem can occur, you can either synchronize the event handling code or marshal it to be executed on a specific thread (as you would to the UI Thread in case an UI Component is being modified). If you chose to synchronize, make the event handling code as short as possible to keep your program responsive. But the exact methodology would highly depend on what the handler is actually supposed to do.

Comment: I have created a sample project which works just fine using multiple event producers and there are no thread safety problems. Please have a look at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-dic8zDHCwKZVZ5YXFmcmN6aGc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty way would be to have a lock. Probably the best place to put that lock would be inside the MessageReceived method, so that it would kick in whenever that method is called. SOmething like this:

```
private object _messageReceivedLock = new object();

private void MessageReceived(Sender object, MessageReceivedEventArgs msg)
{
    lock (_messageReceivedLock)
    {
        // the rest of the MessageReceived body goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this solution around but I dont want to use locks due to performance reasons

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil :) It is better practice to get at least to a a working prototype, and then you can identify the parts of your code that take too long to execute. Very often, the places that actually need improvement, are not the places you would have guessed.

Comment: I know but I am writing a high perf service that uses no locks to avoid context switching.

Comment: In that case @codejunkie, you'd need to show your event Handler. The "best" approach will depend on what it is actually doing. But I guess you won't come around using at least *some* synchronization here. But an alternative could be to use some sort of lock-free datastructure or simply marshalling to the UI-Thread to ensure "happens-before"-behavior.

Comment: I am not using any UI. It is a high performance service that does some CPU bound OPs.

Comment: Well, as Fildor said - without knowing what is going on in that MessageReceived method, we can't be more specific. In most cases, you actually would not need to have the lock around entire function body.  But as we cannot see the function, we cannot tell. 

Generally, unless there are awful lot of threads accessing the same thing, lock performance is just fine. If it later turns out that the lock actually does affect performance, you can then refactor it to using SemaphoreSlim or something.

Comment: @codejunkie:  _"uses no locks to avoid context switching"_ -- non sequitur. If there is contention, context switching is unavoidable, whether you use `lock` or not. If there is no contention, `lock` will not cause context switching. You are confused. That said, your original question is too broad; your event-raising implementation is itself inherently not thread-safe (you're just asking for a `NullReferenceException`), and whether the invocation itself is thread-safe depends on the handlers, not the events.